# How to add a set values for key to Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript variable:

```
this.Edges = {};
```

Then I did

```
this.Edges[path] = {edgeDst};
```

So Edges variable at this point is somehing like

*Edges['232kb32i23'] = { edgeDst: 'AND_m_5' }*

after that I when I did

```
this.Edges[path] = {edgeSrc};
```

It overwrote the value I had added with edgeDst.
At this point Edges is like following:

*Edges['232kb32i23'] = { edgeSrc: 'B_m_5' }*

But I want to produce something like:
*Edges['232kb32i23'] = { edgeDst: 'AND_m_5', edgeSrc: 'B_m_5' }*

Here I can't added edgeSrc and edgeDst simulataneously.

How will I achieve this?

Comment: How do you get both keys and values from doing `= {edgeSrc};` , what's in  `edgeSrc` etc ?

Comment: @adeno - ES2015 or ES2016 has the answer to that

Comment: @JaromandaX - That's what I suspected, hence my question ?

Comment: if you want to add both at the same time, `this.Edges[path] = {edgeDst, edgeSrc};`

Comment: Okay then, if the answer below worked, I guess it wasn't property shorthand after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```js
var Edges = {};                  // these are just so that you can run the snippet
var path = '232kb32i23';

Edges[path] = {};                // set Edges[path] to a new object
Edges[path].edgeDst = 'AND_m_5'; // set the edgeDst property on Edges[path]
Edges[path].edgeSrc = 'B_m_5';   // set the edgeSrc property on Edges[path]

console.log(Edges);              // run the snippet to see the result
console.log(Edges['232kb32i23']);
```

You will have to modify the code to use `this` for your application, but I tried to make as succinct an example as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the new ES6 syntactic sugar. It looks like you can do something like this:

```
this.Edges = {};

var path = 'the_path',
    edgeDst = 'edgeDst',
    edgeSrc = 'edgeSrc';

this.Edges[path] = { edgeDst, edgeSrc };

console.log(this.Edges) => {edgeDs:"AND_m_5",edgeSrc:"edgeSrc"}
```

Here is a link to a functioning example: https://jsfiddle.net/xwf3wadr/